# Help required with audio in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, waveform, wave, energy

I'm trying to write an .m file to extract energy features from an audio track but I seem to be having trouble in its implementation:

```
% Formula for calculating RMS

[f, fs, nb] = wavread('Three.wav');

frameWidth=441; %10ms
numSamples=length(x);
numFrames=(numSamples/1);
energy(frame)=0;

for frame=1:numFrames,
    startSample=(frame-1)*frameWidth+1;
    endSample=startSample+frameWidth-1;
% Calculate frame energy
    for i=startSample:endSample
        energy(frame)=energy(frame)+x(i)^2;
    end
end
```

I run that file in MATLAB and get the following error:

> ??? Attempted to access x(2); index out of bounds because numel(x)=1.
>   Error in ==> myrms at 12
>       energy(frame)=energy(frame)+x(i)^2;

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `f` instead of `x`, since `f` is the actual signal loaded from your .wav file. The variable `x` was probably just some other scalar in your workspace, which is why you were getting the error you saw.

There are a few other corrections/improvements that should be made to your code. First, as [Paul R pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406361/help-required-with-audio-in-matlab/3406399#3406399), you need to correct how you compute `numFrames`. Second, `energy` should be initialized as a vector of zeroes. Third, you can reduce the inner for loop to a one-line vectorized operation.

Here's how I would rewrite your code (*EDIT: Based on comments, I have updated the code to save a few extra variables computed in the loop*):

```
[y, fs, nb] = wavread('Three.wav');  %# Load the signal into variable y

frameWidth = 441;                          %# 10 msec
numSamples = length(y);                    %# Number of samples in y
numFrames = floor(numSamples/frameWidth);  %# Number of full frames in y
energy = zeros(1,numFrames);               %# Initialize energy
startSample = zeros(1,numFrames);          %# Initialize start indices of frame
endSample = zeros(1,numFrames);            %# Initialize end indices of frame

for frame = 1:numFrames                              %# Loop over frames
  startSample(frame) = (frame-1)*frameWidth+1;       %# Starting index of frame
  endSample(frame) = frame*frameWidth;               %# Ending index of frame
  frameIndex = startSample(frame):endSample(frame);  %# Indices of frame samples
  energy(frame) = sum(y(frameIndex).^2);             %# Calculate frame energy
end
```

Comment: Brilliant.

Just noticed the mistake I made in the initial post too, I shouldn't have used f at all, I didn't even have it written down anywhere on the piece of paper where I was writing the initial code. How embarrassing.

Thank you for the help anyway, it's much appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea whether you will get a notification that I have replied to this but here goes anyway.

Is there a way to apply a label or tag to each frame that is created? Even if it is as basic as "Frame 1""Frame 2" etc.

I want to perform a few functions myself to find the areas of the song that I want to extract, but I have no idea how to recall the frames once I have that data.

For instance if I perform auto-correlation and then peak detection functions, I then want to map that frame back to its specific position within the song so that I can then extract the thumbnail.

Comment: @Velocity: One way to do that is to save the values of `startSample` and `endSample` that you compute in your loop. I've updated the code in my answer to show how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this line:

```
numFrames=(numSamples/1);
```

be something like:

```
numFrames=(numSamples / frameWidth);
```

or possibly:

```
numFrames=((numSamples + frameWidth - 1) / frameWidth);
```

?

Comment: I originally had:

numFrames=flux(numSamples/numFrames)

but MATLAB didn't like that either.

Comment: A call to [FLOOR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/floor.html) may also be needed in case `numFrames` doesn't come out as an exact integer.

Comment: Yes, total idiocy on my part. I couldn't read my own scrawly handwriting. FLOOR is what I wanted, not flux.